# Firebase ALL level Child Search

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I trying retrieve data from firebase.

[image]

Rules :

```
    {
      "rules": {
       "restricted_access": {
            "secret_document" : {
                "message": {
                    ".indexOn": ".value"
            }
          } 
       }
     }
   }
```

Rest API Call :

[https://MyApp.firebaseio.com/restricted_access/secret_document/message.json?orderBy="$value"&equalTo="Course](https://MyApp.firebaseio.com/restricted_access/secret_document/message.json?orderBy=%22$value%22&equalTo=%22Course) Learning"

but result blank : {} when I call API

[image]

when I put "Course Learning" value direct in message then its show result. I need all child level result. message/1/-NCxlHCIYEEewvo2gIKW also have value but its not return in result.

Json structure I can't change and "-NCxlHCIYEEewvo2gIKW" dynamic generated so can't add in rule.
how can I get all level child for message?

Answer (score 0):

A Firebase Realtime Database query can only have a single unknown key in its path. At a glance it seems that in your data structure both the `1` and the `-N...` key are unknown. If that is correct, you won't be able to query for `notificationType`.

Also see: [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)